# Theme Hacking. Carousels stop working after remove() lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

*EDIT*

Ok, the problem is `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 3000);`
Seems to interfere with bootstrap carousel functionality. How can I repurpose this to not interfere with rest of document? There's a header carousel and post carousel that doesn't function after lightbox popup.

*Original Post*

Long story short, this fell into my lap, it's a bloated pre-built theme and client wanted to customize. They wanted some front end edits, couldn't easily reverse engineer how it was built, so targeting elements with JS and replacing divs with my own markup. All fine there, except when I created the lightbox, it seems to interfere with carousel functionality, it stops working. Any ideas what I could be missing here? Thanks

```js
if (document.querySelector(".home")) {

document.querySelector(".nk-header-title").innerHTML = `

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide nk-header-title-sm nk-header-title-parallax-opacity" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">


        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('./wp-content/images/Wells-Street-Market-Header.jpg')" alt="First slide">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('./wp-content/images/wsm-group.jpg')" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="overlay"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('./wp-content/images/wsm-mixology.jpg')" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="overlay"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('./wp-content/images/wsm-sidewalk.jpg')" alt="Fourth slide">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('./wp-content/images/wsm-donuts.jpg')" alt="Fifth slide">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>



    <div class="nk-header-table">
        <div class="nk-header-table-cell">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="nk-subtitle" style="color: #ffffff;">205 W. Wacker Dr. Chicago Open M-F 11AM-8PM</h2>

                <h1 class="nk-title display-3" style="color: #ffffff;">WELLS STREET MARKET</h1>

                <div class="nk-gap-2"></div>
                <div style="color: #ffffff;">
                    <div class="nk-gap-4">(See vendors below for specific hours)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div><!-- /carousel-inner -->





</div><!-- /carouselControls -->


`;
 
    
    document.querySelector(".nk-awb-overlay").innerHTML = `

<div class="nk-awb-overlay" style="background-image: url('./wp-content/images/map_background.png')"></div>

`;
    
    
    
setTimeout(function(){
    
        
document.querySelector(".home").innerHTML += `

<div class="lightbox-container">
  
   <div class="sign-up-container">

   <span onclick="document.querySelector('.lightbox-container').remove()">

<i class="fa fa-times"></i>

</span>


<h3 class="sign_up_text">
Good Eats in your Inbox
</h3>



<img class="sign_up_icons" src="./wp-content/images/sign_up_icons.svg" alt="sign up icons">


<p class="sign_up_text">Sign up for the Wells Street Market newsletter to receive exclusive offers, keep up with events and more.</p>



<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://workwithdomino.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=c61f2c9cc665c03dfdef8af98&amp;id=e68bd54a90" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">



<div class="mc-field-group">
 
 <input type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name" name="FNAME" class="mc_form" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>

<div class="mc-field-group">
 
 <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name" name="LNAME" class="mc_form" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>


<div class="mc-field-group">

 <input type="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address" name="EMAIL" class="mc_form required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>


 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
 </div>   


<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_c61f2c9cc665c03dfdef8af98_e68bd54a90" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->


</div>


</div>
`;


}, 3000);
```

Comment: Are your single quotes closing out your innerHTML too early?

Comment: hmmm, i'm using template strings backticks `, should that matter?

Comment: i found it....
setTimeout() is the culprit, interfering with the carousel functionality.